# What distribution options are there for internal iOS applications?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am going to be working on a project that involves an inventory scanning system at a video production company, and they want to be able to sign in / sign out inventory using an iPhone or an iPad, which will require a native app.

Since this app will only be on one or two different devices, and will only be for internal use, is it necessary to go through the app store to distribute it? Can it be permanently distributed to those devices by some other means?

Answer (score 2):

You either want an [ADHOC build](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW21) (which allows you to build for 100 - 200 devices), or you want your company to get [an Enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/), which allows you to distribute within your company internally.

Comment: Ad Hoc build now allows up to 500 devices (including 100 iPads, 100 iPhone, 100 Apple TV, 100 iPod Touch and 100 Apple WATCH) and the App will need to be re-installed in 3 months, as Provisioning Profile expired.